# jQuery selector <button></button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have the following situation:

```
<div id="topDiv">
    <div class="buttonDiv1">
         <button class="buttonClass">Click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonDiv2">
         <button class="buttonClass">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that these are **not** *input[type='button']*
I am trying to select the two buttons under the topDiv and change their class.

```
$('#topDiv button').removeClass('buttonClass').addClass('classButton');
```

It does not work. 
Please any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is `button` not inside the quotes? as it stands now it's not even valid javascript, much less a jquery selector. It's like asking why does this not work? `var x = 1 2;`

Comment: Tip: always validate your code first, see here http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: @elclanrs thak you very much for the great tip. I have been looking for something like this.

Comment: @Kevin B I do not see why "Why **var x = 1 2;** does not work?" would not be a valid question in this forum!? Thank you for making me realize that knowledge should not make me ignorant and resentful of the ones that just started accumulating it. Your "teaching" approach is the least productive, there are plenty of studies on any level about that, and here you are not even a teacher, but mere participant! I hope you would not teach anywhere until you learn that profession.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need button within the single quotes.

```
$('#topDiv button').removeClass('buttonClass').addClass('classButton');
```

Comment: @Georgi Maybe I'm not sure what you're trying to do then.  This works - [http://jsfiddle.net/9SVZM/](http://jsfiddle.net/9SVZM/)

Comment: @NaNpx_ Thank you for the example. I am not sure why I cannot make it work yet. Does it matter whether the <button> is a grand child or a grand grand grand child? Thanks again

Comment: @Georgi it doesn't matter, `$('#topDiv button')` selector gets all button elements within the element with an id of topDiv.  Post some code or update the existing JSFiddle, maybe I'm missing some info on what you're trying to accomplish.